# infinite sum and integral representation

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

assuming all the numbers $ k_{n} $ are REAL is then true that

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k_{n}^{s}}=\frac{1}{2 \Gamma (s) cos(\pi s)}\int_{0}^{\infty}dtt^{s-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}cos(k_{n}t) $$

by term integration this sum should be correct but not 100 % sure.

Comment: Are you using $x_n$ as the $n$th falling factorial of $x$?